# Using values outside a form in MVC 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-partialview

I have a standard form in a PartialView, loaded by an Ajax.ActionLink. When posting back the form I would also like to use a couple of values from elements on the page outside of the form in the PartialView.

Is this possible? What's the best way to get this done?

Thanks.

Comment: create hidden elements that have the values you want as copied using a javascript function onsubmit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is absolutely possible.  Just use javascript to copy the values from the page into the form when the form is submitted, or beforehand.

Using jQuery:

```
$(function () {
    $('form').submit(function () {
        // either copy the values into elements already in the form
        // or, copy the elements themselves and place them in the form
    });
});
```

Comment: I'm using Ajax.BeginForm to create the form, so I assume I can do it before the form is submitted through one of the AjaxOptions properties? Just have to figure out which one, i.e. OnBegin, etc.

Comment: @DanyW `OnBegin` does seem to be the right one.  From MSDN, *"Gets or sets the name of the JavaScript function to call immediately before the page is updated."*